# Two Plastic ATP Certs?

Tags: pilot-certification

I recently got typed in the CL-65 and received my restricted ATP certification. I can’t figure out why but apparently due to the amount of limitations such as PIC in accordance with 61.167 and vmc circle only and Cl-65 vmc circle only lines, they added the rest onto a second plastic certificate. I have a 1 of 2 and a 2 of 2 card. Has anyone seen or heard of this happening to them or anyone else?

Comment: I've seen one pilot with so many additional ratings and limitations they had three plastic cards.

Answer (score 2):

I used to have 2 (U.S.) ATP paper certificates ("Card 1 of 2" and "Card 2 of 2" - printed on the 2 certificates). Before plastic certificates were issued the back of pilot certificates did not contain any certificate or rating specifics, just some information regarding "Duration" and other general info.

I had ratings in 3 different aircraft categories and some type ratings shown on card 1.  On card 2 the verbiage relating to my balloon rating and its associated limitation ("Limited to Hot Air Balloons with Airborne Heater") was too lengthy to fit on card 1.

Since the new plastic certificates use both the front and back, all of the rating and limitation information shown above now fit on my single plastic ATP certificate.

I imagine that since the certificate, rating and limitation information you mention in your question is so lengthy, it requires 2 (plastic) certificates (cards).  So, it is not unprecedented to have a pilot certificate require more than a single card.

Comment: I've had jumpseaters present two-card ATP certificates a few times.  First time is puzzling; after that it's just a case of lots of type ratings & some amount of other verbiage. But definitely possible, and not wildly rare.

Comment: What type of hot air balloon exists that does not have an airborne heater?

Comment: @Someone none that I'm aware of. Maybe the wording (which seems a bit redundant) is to clearly eliminate gas balloons.  But, that's the wording on my certificate.